# PHP Display multi-dimentional array value on google map

Tags: javascript, php, implode

Can anyone help me, I am very new to PHP, maybe the answer was very obvious.

I store users details and postcodes in the database, then I need to display the postcodes as markers on the google map using javascript (this was working).

But I was trying to display each user data on google map's info window, I am only be able to display the last row of the result, so all info windows were display the same record, not the individual data to that postcode.

I think I need to combine below two queries, but I don't know how. Because the postcode need to be implode to get "postcode" to show on map.

**What I am trying to achieve:**

```
postcode need to be ("AA4 1DD", "AB1  5CD","CC4 1BBs");
infowindow (Fred, 7 street, AA4 1DD);
```

**What I have in the Database:**

```
name       Fred           Ann         John
address    7 street      8 road       4 line
postcode   AA4 1DD       AB1  5CD     CC4 1BB
```

**PHP:**

```
         try {
         $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
         $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
         $locations = $conn->prepare("SELECT postcode FROM tbl_data"); 
         $locations->execute();
         $lo= $locations->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
         echo  "'". $t = implode(' ,', $lo)."'";// working

        //info window
        $info_stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT name, postcode FROM tbl_data, tbl_login WHERE tbl_data.user_id=tbl_login.user_id ");
        $info_stmt->execute();

        $result = $info_stmt -> fetchAll();

          foreach( $result as $row ) {
              echo $row[0];
           /*   echo "<pre>";
              echo gettype($row[0]);
              echo "</pre>";*/
          }

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
         echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
         die();
         }
```

**Javascript:**

```
 var addressArray = new Array(<?php echo "'". $t = implode("' ,'", $lo)."'"; ?>); //postcodes working


    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
         for (var i = 0; i < addressArray.length; i++) {
            geocoder.geocode( { 'address': addressArray[i]}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                    title: 'Click for more details'
                });

               //create info window 
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: "<p>Name: </p><?php echo $row[0].'<br />'.$row[1]; ?>"
            });
```

Comment: `$row` is used like this: `$row['columnName']`

Comment: Thanks for your reply @KyleE4K yes, when I try to use javascript call this out only the last  record displayed for all my info windows, I don't know how to link each postcode to that data row. I thought I should use sql query link ids, it worked in phpmyadmin but not on marker info windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
 content: "<p>Food Name: </p><?php echo $row[0].'<br />'.$row[1]; ?>"
```

You cannot mix JavaScript and PHP like this, and $row does not - or shouldn't - actually exist in this context due to it not being within the `foreach` statement or - if this is a seperate JS file - you have no corresponding context.

To achieve what you need, I'd suggest using AJAX and setting a `GET` request to a file which then returns an array which you can then use in your JavaScript.

You can read documentation on this [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/).

Note, `$row` should be used like this: `$row['ColumnName']` (not just for readability).

For example: `echo $row['address'];`

**Example Code (PHP):**

```
try {
     $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
     $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
     $locations = $conn->prepare("SELECT postcode FROM tbl_data"); 
     $locations->execute();
     $lo= $locations->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
     echo  "'". $t = implode(' ,', $lo)."'";// working

    //info window
    $info_stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT name, postcode FROM tbl_data, tbl_login WHERE tbl_data.user_id=tbl_login.user_id ");
    $info_stmt->execute();

    echo $info_stmt->fetchAll();

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

**Then your JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var output[];
   $.get("phpfile.php")
     .done(function(data) {
       output = data;
     });
});
```

`output` is now the array of all your `results` and can be used.

Comment: Thank you very appreciated, I am trying this now

Comment: Not a problem, but I advise not to `echo $row`, neither `foreach` it. `echo` the whole array and then in the response, you can use it as an array. See example code in edited answer